# rename files recursively by adding a string at the beggining of file in linux

Tags: rename, batch-rename

i tried many commands. No one did the job.
how to use rename / find or something else to add a string at the start of files in subfolders, reculsively?

example `file.jpg --> image_file.jpg`

```
find . -name '*.jpg'  -exec  rename  -n "s/^/image_/" *.jpg {} +
for pic in '*.jpg' ; do  rename  -n "s/^/image_/ ${pic}"; done
find . -name '*.jpg'  -exec rename -n "s/^/image_/ .jpg '{}' \;
find "/files/" -type f -exec rename 's/^/image_/' '{}' \;
find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "$1" "${1/^/image_/}"' -- {} \;
```

why this says `Invalid cross-device link`
`find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir rename  's:./:/image_:' {} +`

Comment: If you're trying to add the *character* `^`, you need to escape it with a back-slash.

Comment: No, see the example provided how i would like to rename files

Comment: (1) What `rename` is this? [There are few](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618) and for each one there may be a setup where it is named `rename`. (2) Does your `find` support `-execdir`?

Comment: yes it supports execdir, i am in debian linux

Answer (score 0):

Ι found it! This command add a string at the beginning of each file recursively in all sub directories. I dont know yet why it works but works. Ρemove '-n' for actual results.

`find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir rename  -n 's:./:./image_:' {} +`

example of result: `rename(./28652316400.jpg, ./image_28652316400.jpg)`

- `s` means substitute.
- `:` as i understood, it means to go to first occurance of "." then while you went to ".", then substitute with "image_" and exit.
  (i may be wrong however). Read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31673/what-purpose-does-the-colon-builtin-serve/771060#771060) more about the meaning of colon in bash and scripts.

Comment: Don't forget to add appropriate filename selector in the `-name '*.jpg'` such that rerun's don't cause the creation of `image_image_*.jpg`.